# Mysql : Column getting Null entries

Tags: mysql

trying to write some data into MySQL and I'm getting NULL values.

For example :

```
+------------+-------------+
| Start_time | Bucket_name |
+------------+-------------+
| 2017053007 | NULL        |
| 2017053007 | NULL        |
| 2017053007 | NULL        |
| 2017053007 | NULL        |
| 2017053008 | NULL        |
| 2017053008 | NULL        |
| 2017053008 | NULL        |
| 2017053008 | NULL        |
| 2017053008 | NULL        |
| 2017053008 | NULL        |
| 2017053008 | NULL        |
| 2017053009 | NULL        |
| 2017053009 | NULL        |
|       NULL | East3       |
|       NULL | East5       |
|       NULL | East7       |
|       NULL | East9       |
|       NULL | East11      |
```

First I write the data into "Start_time" Field and when I write Data into Bucket_name it Starts from the end of "Start_time" instead of first row.

Is there a way to get this aligned correctly?

I do some normal calculations and write the data to a file and use "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE" to write it to DB.

Thanks.

Comment: bro you need to add primary key  to table than you need to update it not insert it

Comment: Are you asking how to use `LOAD DATA` to update existing rows?

Comment: Yes; @Álvaro González ... I have many columns; so how to insert/update data to those columns from ID 1( considering ID 1 as the Primary Key ) with LOAD DATA.

Comment: As far as I know you cannot. You need to load stuff into a temporary table and make the updates later. E.g.: [How to: Use MySQL fast LOAD DATA for UPDATEs](http://www.softwareprojects.com/resources/programming/t-how-to-use-mysql-fast-load-data-for-updates-1753.html)